# How do I search iTunes using Applescript?

Tags: applescript

How do I search for every song match certain criteria?  E.g., something like:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set tracks to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name contains "Green")
    repeat with t in tracks
        display dialog (t as string)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like that, except for two things; first, `tracks` is a reserved word in the iTunes scripting dictionary, so replace it with something else (*e.g.* `ts`); second, you can't just convert a track to a string with `t as string`; you have to choose what information you want.  For instance, if you want the name, you can use `name of t as string`; if you want more detail, you could do `name of t & " - " & artist of t`; etc.  Note also that if you want a more complicated predicate, you can just tack it on to the `whose` clause; for instance, `file tracks whose name contains "Green" and artist contains "Bird"`.

If you want to golf the script a little, you could replace it with the following:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (file tracks whose name contains "Green")
        display dialog (name of t as string)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Removing the `of playlist "Library"` might produce slightly different results, but probably not.  It didn't in my quick testing.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out it's a reserved word.  Changing it did the trick.  Thanks!